# Change own OS from 32bit to 64bit

Tags: makefile, ld

I'm writing my own OS. But in the tutorial (https://github.com/AlgorithMan-de/wyoos/commit/7eb9f8a1d5089cf7587e553e601c42db34dc94a2) he is writing it for i386 arch with x86_32. But now I want to change it to x86_64.

Now I have to replace a few things in the Makefile and in the Linker (like the OUTPUT_ARCH()) but I don't now what I should write there instead.

linker.ld

```
ENTRY(loader)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:i386)

SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x0100000;

  .text :
  {
    *(.multiboot)
    *(.text*)
    *(.rodata)
  }

  .data  :
  {
    start_ctors = .;
    KEEP(*( .init_array ));
    KEEP(*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY( .init_array.* )));
    end_ctors = .;

    *(.data)
  }

  .bss  :
  {
    *(.bss)
  }

  /DISCARD/ : { *(.fini_array*) *(.comment) }
}
```

Makefile

```
GCCPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386

objects = loader.o kernel.o



%.o: %.cpp
    gcc $(GCCPARAMS) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

**EDIT**

I have now edited the Makefile and the linker.ld

Makefile

```
GCCPARAMS = -m64 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore
ASPARAMS = --64
LDPARAMS = -melf_x86_64

objects = loader.o kernel.o



%.o: %.cpp
    gcc $(GCCPARAMS) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin
```

linker.ld

```
ENTRY(loader)
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)

SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x0100000;

  .text :
  {
    *(.multiboot)
    *(.text*)
    *(.rodata)
  }

  .data  :
  {
    start_ctors = .;
    KEEP(*( .init_array ));
    KEEP(*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY( .init_array.* )));
    end_ctors = .;

    *(.data)
  }

  .bss  :
  {
    *(.bss)
  }

  /DISCARD/ : { *(.fini_array*) *(.comment) }
}
```

But when I try to compile it (`ld -melf_x86_64 -T linker.ld -o mykernel.bin loader.o kernel.o`), I get an error:

```
ld: loader.o: in function 'loader':
(.text+0x6): undefined reference to 'eax'
ld: (.text+0xb): undefined reference to 'ebx'
ld: (.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'kernelMain'
```

I think I have to install a binutil but I don't know which one.

Can someone help me finding the right one?

Comment: Needs a link to the tutorial referenced here.

Comment: https://github.com/AlgorithMan-de/wyoos/commit/7eb9f8a1d5089cf7587e553e601c42db34dc94a2 this is the code from the tutorial

Comment: Please edit question to include it then.